# user " is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: "

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-eks

I created a EKS cluster on aws, and when I tried to access it from aws cli, I bumped into access right issue.

-- my cli user permssion:

[image]

-- definition of policy sts_AssumeRol,

[image]

-- then when I try to run

```
siguser@x220:~/ws/aws/eks$ ./kubectl get svc

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/shichao-aws-cli is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/eks-sg-bd-role
```

what could be the possible cause here? i have tried to run >>aws configure a few times, but to no avail.

============================== edit 1:=======================

trust relationship for role eks-sg-bd-role:
[image]

policy simulator:

[image]

============================== edit 2:=======================
[image]

```
siguser@x220:~/ws/aws/eks$ ./kubectl get svc
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

my own solution:

i end up working around the issue with eksctl instead.

```
eksctl create cluster --name eks-cluster-SG-BD --version 1.16 --region us-east-2 --fargate
```

Comment: What is the trust policy on `eks-sg-bd-role` role?

Comment: @Marcin, thanks! edit above.

Comment: The trust policy is for `eks.amazonaws.com`, not for IAM user `shichao-aws-cli`. Your error message says that `shichao-aws-cli` tries to assume `eks-sg-bd-role` , which is obviously denied, because the trust policy allows this action only for  `eks.amazonaws.com` service.

Comment: @Marcin, I have added aws user to my trust relationship for eks-sg-bd-role; however, I got a new error here. any clue?

Comment: @sqr I hope this might be helpful. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-api-server-unauthorized-error/